# How to add an Icon to my costum Pie menu?

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

I want to add an Icon to my pie menu. How I can do that?

[image]

```
import bpy
 from bpy.types import Menu, Operator
    
    class MY_EXTRUDE(bpy.types.Operator):
   
    bl_idname = "my.extrude"
    bl_label = "Extrude"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.view3d.edit_mesh_extrude_move_normal()
        return {'FINISHED'}
     class Extrude_plus_plus(Menu):
    
    bl_label = "Extrude + +"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        
        pie.operator("my.extrude")
     


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Extrude_plus_plus)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_EXTRUDE)

    
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Extrude_plus_plus)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_EXTRUDE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="Extrude_plus_plus")
```

Comment: `pie.operator("my.extrude", icon="MOD_SOLIDIFY")` ? see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.operator

Comment: @Gorgious ah that works thanks ^^